# How to insert main method Netbeans in Mac pc (shortcut)

Tags: java, macos, netbeans

I know there is a shortcut java in netbeans for write main method. just type psvm and press Tab.

but it don't not work Mac. how can i do it on Mac pc in netbeans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a code template, but don’t be affraid, it’s really simple. First go to the preferences of NetBeans, then in the “Editor” part and click on the tab “Code templates”. You should be there :

[image]

Then click on “New”. In the window, type the text You have to write. It’s Your shortcut  For the main method generation, type “main”  It’s not original but instinctive 
In the list, Your new abbreviation is selected. In the text area called “Expended Text”, enter this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
${cursor}
}
```

You’ve successfully created a main template 
Now in Your class, just type “main” and press the Tab button, and Your main body will be created 
It’s nice, it’s simple, it’s Java 
Enjoy